Is it possible to implement Stripe payment only using API?
I would like to implement different payment gateways and one of them would be Stripe.
Stripe has its own way of implement payment, such as specific components in the frontend.
I would like to create my own component in react.js that can handle user's data and card for different payment gateways.
Searching in the Stripe docs, it says:

Create a Payment Intent and retrieve the client secret (my node server);
Collect payment details on the client (my custom component);
Call stripe.confirmPayment

But I haven't found how to do the step 3 without installing stripe.js.
Is it possible to complete the whole payment process without installing any Stripe library? I mean only using Stripe API.
If so, please, provide some code example.

It is possible, but it's very much not recommended, and requires you to be fully PCI compliant since you'll be handling raw card data yourself.  You'll also need to handle things like 3D Secure completely manually, which can be a significant amount of extra effort if you require things like that.
There are no existing code samples I'm aware of because Stripe discourages this type of integration, even if it is technically possible.  I think you may also need permission from Stripe to integrate this way, so you might want to reach out to their support for further assistance.
